# How to mock a single value in a React Context provider while keeping the rest of values

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-context

Hi I have a context provider which returns like this:

```
return (
        <RepeatsSidebarContext.Provider
            value={{
                loading,
                designRepeats,
                handleShowCreateRepeatItem,
                handleShowCreateRepeatItemSmartSelvedge,
                createRepeatItem,
                handleCreateNewRepeat,
                handleCreateSmartSelvedge,
                nextRepeatName,
                handleUpdateRepeat,
                nativeRepeatsIcons,
                handleSortRepeats,
                onRepeatUpdate,
                createSmartSelvedgeItem,
            }}
        >
            {children}
        </RepeatsSidebarContext.Provider>
    );
};

export default RepeatsSidebarProvider;
```

And I would like only to mock the  `designRepeats` value. It would be something like:

```
render(<RepeatsSidebarProvider value={{designRepeatsMock}}>
            <RepeatSidebarItem {...props} />
        </RepeatsSidebarProvider>)
```

But if I do like this, the prop value is set by only `designRepeats`value so the rest of values get overwritten.

Would appreciate some help. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this way to mock the context with using a wrapper where I recreate the provider.

```
const wrapper = ({ children }) => (
            <RepeatsSidebarContext.Provider
                value={{
                    ...initialStateMock,
                    designRepeatsMock
                }}
            >
                {children}
            </RepeatsSidebarContext.Provider>
        );


    test("myTest",()=>{
render(<RepeatSidebarItem />, {wrapper})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In your component you can use the context you have returned by useContext hook and alter the value of RepeatSidebarItem as you want it to be.

Comment: If I am not wrong, It is a test, the solution should be something I could do within the test. Could you provide an example of how to do what you explained within a test?

Comment: It is not a test. I am using it my self in my day to day working.

Comment: I think there is a missunderstood. I want to mock it in a test. My component works fine as it is.

Comment: Please see how useContext work and in the Component RepeatSidebarItem, get and change the value of context however you want.

Comment: As I said, it is not about changing the componenent. I want to mock the value in my test.